# Is there a way to refresh page without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, back-button, laravel-5.3

I'm still looking for way to automate refresh in my page. But I'm confused on how to solve this problem without using jQuery and solving it using Laravel 5.3 functions. If someone knows how to solve this please help. It would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use html tag <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30"> where 30 is seconds.

Comment: It doesn't work sir thanks for the help

Comment: Can you explain little more, like you want to refresh once or regularly, at what interval or time it should refresh. And also paste you controller method  where you are returning response.

Comment: My main goal is to refresh my page when i clicked the back button above i want it to be possible without using jQuery. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is JavaScript basics.

Try this:

```
<body onload="if (location.href.indexOf('reload')==-1) location.replace(location.href+'?reload');">
```

Comment: Wow Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

`header("Refresh:0");` should do the trick. (In PHP)

`location.reload();` should do it in plain old js.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

These are the way you can reload page :

window.location.reload(); in JavaScript

in HTML (where 1 = 1 second).

window.location.reload()

location.reload(true/false);
If false, the page will be reloaded from cache, else from the server.

Comment: Thanks for the help